# MVC5 view drop down list from ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownbox

I'm new to MVC5/C# (fresh off a Silverlight project) and have a web application (not ASP.net) that I'm working on. I can't figure out how to get the value from a dropdown list that is populated from a ViewBag and not the model. Everything I've seen is geared towards ASP.NET and/or populating the dropdown from the model.

I have this model for shifts:

```
   public class Shift
   {
      public Guid ShiftID { get; set; }
      public string AreaOfOperation { get; set; }
      public string UserName { get; set; }
      public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
      public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
   }
```

And this for AreaOfOperations:

```
   public class AreaOfOperations
   {
      public Guid AreaOfOperationsID { get; set; }
      public String AreaOfOperation { get; set; }
      public bool InUse { get; set; }      
   }
```

The relevant controller code, which populates the view nicely with a working dropdown:

```
  public ActionResult Create(DateTime? datetime)
  {
     List<AreaOfOperations> list = db.AreaOfOperations.Where(i => i.InUse == true).OrderBy(aoo => aoo.AreaOfOperation).ToList();
     ViewBag.DropDownAOOs = new SelectList(list, "AreaOfOperationsID", "AreaOfOperation");

     Shift shift = new Shift();
     shift.ShiftID = Guid.NewGuid();
     shift.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
     shift.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
     return View(shift);
  }

  // POST: Shifts/Create
  // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
  // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ShiftID,AreaOfOperations,UserName,StartTime")] Shift shift)
  {
     try
     {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           shift.ShiftID = Guid.NewGuid();
           db.Shifts.Add(shift);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
     }
     catch (DataException /* dex */)
     {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
     }
     return View(shift);
  }
```

And my view:

```
@model CRMgr5.Models.Shift

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Start Shift";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Shift</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaOfOperations, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("AreaOfOperation", ViewBag.DropDownAOOs as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="btnStartShift" type="submit" value="Start Shift" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are from Silverlight then you may be interested in using the strong Binding technique, but I hesitate to show you because you are using the ViewBag.  I personally can't stand working with the ViewBag.  That's why I didn't show you what I'd do, but you'd get it right away because it's the same thing as MVVM except on MVC.  Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value to send back to the server or is your dropdown not populating?

Comment: Yes, Bill, I'm asking how to get the value back to the server. My dropdown is populating fine. The shift information is getting populated, except for the shift's AreaOfOpertaions property, which I need to get from the dropdown.

Comment: Try @Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.AreaOfOperation, ViewBag.DropDownAOOs as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }))

Comment: I tried your suggestion @Florian, but got an InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'AreaOfOperation'.

Answer (score 2):

In the drop down list you named your select as "AreaOfOperation" but the model property is called "AreaOfOperations." Hence the binder will not be able to bind it.

As someone here already suggested you should use strongly typed html helpers such as DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AreaOfOperations, ViewBag.DropDownAOOs as SelectList)
```

You did it for the label not sure why you opted not to use it when generating a drop down list?

Comment: I changed one of the Shift class member's names to remove some of the confusion. It's now AreaOfOperation so it doesn't share the same name as the AreaOfOperations class.

Any way, I tried your suggestion and got InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'AreaOfOperation' on this line in my view:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AreaOfOperation, ViewBag.DropDownAOOs as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated the whole thing and it worked fine

I removed the s of AreaOfOperations in your Bind Attribute

```
[Bind(Include = "ShiftID,AreaOfOperation(s),UserName,StartTime")]
```

As far as i know, you can remove this parameter attribute alltogether.
This is only used when you only want to bind to certain Attributes of your view model.

However there was one mistake: you have to repopulate the Select List if your ModelState is not valid. Otherwise your

```
  return View(shift);
```

does not have the data to render a new SelectList.

Another approach is that you put the data in your ViewModel and initialize it in the default constructor. Then you dont have to worry about the data or casting.

Comment: Oops, I guess I was too quick on the gun. It worked once, but now I'm getting `The ViewData item that has the key 'AreaOfOperation' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'`

Comment: Did you repopulate the viewbag? The view needs the data.

Comment: Where? In the HttpPost Create? I added it right above the

`return View(shift);`

that you mentioned in your original post and now it doesn't crash, but the check for ModelState.IsValid always returns false.